# flutter run error and gradle failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

While running the flutter application, encountered following error which shows flutter gradle exited with code 1

I've encountered with another random error and after solving that error I've faced the following error and after googling I found out that corrupt pubspec.yaml file is the culprit here but I couldn't find what causing error.

here's my pubspec.yaml file

```
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+5

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons:
flutter_icons:
  image_path:"Icons/pop-up.png"
  android:true
  ios:true
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
connectivity:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth:
  gradient_widgets:
  connectivity:
  rxdart:
  shimmer:
  transparent_image:
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_core:
  camera:
  flutter_search_bar:
  image_cropper:
  image_picker:
  firebase_database:
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_messaging: '5.1.2'
  shared_preferences:
  firebase_storage:

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

and after running the  'flutter run -v' I got following errors

```
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:507:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      buildGradleProject (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:346:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/apk.dart:34:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:426:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:371:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:251:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:469:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#13     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#14     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#15     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
#17     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#22     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#23     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#24     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#26     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#27     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#28     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#29     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#30     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#33     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#34     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#35     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#36     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#38     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#39     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#40     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#41     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#42     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#43     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#44     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#45     main (file:///Users/pranithrao/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#46     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean` and then run again `flutter pub get`?